# How do I get the characters inside a pair of parentheses which are immediately followed by a specific string?

Tags: regex

My string looks like this:

```
(left.e0_coefficient*right.Scalar) e₀ + (left.e1_coefficient*right.Scalar) e₁ + (left.e2_coefficient*right.Scalar) e₂ + (left.e3_coefficient*right.Scalar) e₃
```

I want to get the expression thats contained in the parentheses preceeding e₂ => `left.e2_coefficient*right.Scalar`

I tried using `\((.+?)\) e₂` however despite it being lazy (non-greedy) the capturing group still contains everything from the first parenthesis in the string to the one immediately before e₂ => `left.e0_coefficient*right.Scalar) e₀ + (left.e1_coefficient*right.Scalar) e₁ + (left.e2_coefficient*right.Scalar`

I think I might have to use a positive-lookbehind or some other form of non-greediness, but I cant figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex for your case: `\(([^()]+?)\) e₂`

About laziness: Laziness works not like this. Laziness modifier changes behavior of group for which it's applied, but in your case opening parenthesis is already matched previously.

**Edit:** Word of caution: this regex applies only if you don't have nested parenthesis. If nested parenthesis possible there are two options:

1. You parse whole expression with something like `\([^()]+?\) e0 + \([^()]+?\) e1 + \(([^()]+?)\) e₂ + \([^()]+?\) e3` (if possible)
2. You try to parse expression respecting the balance of parentheses. It is generally not easy or obvious task. (sometimes, depending on regex engine, could be impossible).

Comment: You don't need the question mark to make it non greedy as the negated character class can not cross the `)`.

Comment: Since it already was there I saved it.  Also, for me it is easier to modify such expressions later (less possible hustle with exactly authors problem).